# How to pass argument in nodejs function postwait amqp

Tags: node.js, amqp

I am new to nodejs. I am using [this function](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#connectionqueuename-options-opencallback))

```
connection.queue(name[, options][, openCallback])
```

in nodejs but I am not ablefigure out , how to pass options (passive , durable etc) in function call

Here is my code snippet :

```
 console.log("rabbit mq connnection ready");
            connection.queue('myNotifications_' + userId , {autoDelete:false , durable:true } ,function(q){

                    q.bind('#');
                    console.log('subsscribe to queue');
```

Above I am using json to pass arguments { autodelete:false , durable:true}  but it seems it is not working.

Any help

Comment: do you get any error? Was the queue declared in advance before you started providing those arguments?

Comment: @old_sound : No error , but app show some erroneous behaviour. Anyways I thought it is bug in library postwait-amqp. So i moved to amqplib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved from postwait-amqp to amqplib nodejs . It seems there is some bug in postwait-amqp.